# EWS: What is the ItemId compared to all Identifiers?

Tags: exchangewebservices

In the page for ItemId https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa580234(v=exchg.150).aspx is the remark:

**"The schema that describes this element is located in the IIS virtual directory that hosts Exchange Web Services."**

What does this mean? Can an EWS provider overwrite what the ItemId definition is? If so, how is that configuration set?

For bonus points: 
ItemId is not listed in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605828(v=exchg.150).aspx is ItemId the same as StoreId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> > "The schema that describes this element is located in the IIS virtual directory that hosts Exchange Web Services."

That just refers to the WSDL (and assoicated files) for the webservice which describes elements that make up the SOAP Messages for the service. All the types are also documented in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ee124331(v=exchg.80).aspx

> > What does this mean? Can an EWS provider overwrite what the ItemId definition is? If so, how is that configuration set?

The short answer is no the Id is created by the Exchange Store and is read only to clients. The longer answer is the EWSId is returned from EWS based on the underlying Store properties https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee204402(v=exchg.80).aspx while its not documented it contains the LongTermEntryId and flags that have meaning only to EWS which uses these to access the underlying item (hence it would be considered opaque). Its not something that a client could or should modify.

> > For bonus points: ItemId is not listed in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn605828(v=exchg.150).aspx is ItemId the same as StoreId?

No the ItemId is the Id of the Message/Object https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee201952(v=exchg.80).aspx . The StoreId is Id of the underlying Store/Mailbox where the Message is located https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee203516(v=exchg.80).aspx. If you want to convert between the EWSId and PR_EntryId then use the ConvertId operation.

Comment: So the EWSId is the Id contained within the ItemId tag from ews? (or in c# appointment.Id.UniqueId is the EwsId right?)